# Не отображаются карты android

Tags: android, google-maps-api, google-maps-api-2

При запуске приложения оно нормально включается, появляются кнопки управления картой, уменьшить, увеличить, но вместо самой карты просто белый фон. В манифесте прописал следующее:

```
 <permission
     android:name="com.example.maps_api.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
     android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/>
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
    ...
        <meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
    android:value="мой_ключ"></meta-data>
```

скачал чужое приложение, но все так же не работает. Запускаю на HTC sensation, версия 4.0.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Смотри в логкате, определенно чтот с ключами/доступами не корректно сделал

Answer (score 0):

Соберите подписаную версию